# Single sign on with mod_auth_cas and custom login

Tags: apache, tomcat, single-sign-on, cas, httpd.conf

I have a web application running on Apache Tomcat. I'm considering using an Apache http server (httpd) with mod_auth_cas to support single sign on. At the same time, i need to use a custom login page for users login (not the default login page that already exists from the CAS server).

Is it feasible to provide a custom login page while using mod_auth_cas? How? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not suppose to do this. Mod_auth_cas is going to redirect your users to a completely different web page, which they trust, and that login screen is out of your control. Also, your CAS provider will not approve of this approach, unless YOU are the CAS provider.

Your CAS provider will not approve because to do this custom page would mean you would have to ask users to enter their credentials directly into your application so that your application can then send them to the CAS server. Most security providers/CAS Servers, will not trust you with that is the entire reason why you are using the CAS protocol and not going directly to the security providers database. So that if you get hacked, the hackers obtain no passwords or credentials. It makes each Mod_Auth_Cas user very low risk for the CAS Server.

But if for some reason you have a high degree of trust with the CAS server then perhaps they may allow you to create a custom login then submit the users credentials on their behalf...But I highly doubt it.